# iOS - copy all NSMutableAttributedString attributes to another NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, nsmutableattributedstring

I'd like to copy all attributes from one `NSMutableAttributedString` into a new one.  The code i've tried is this:

```
[attrStr enumerateAttribute:NSFontAttributeName inRange:NSMakeRange(0, attrStr.length) options:0 usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
        if (value) {
           // UIFont *oldFont = (UIFont *)value;
            UIFont *newFont = [_label.attributedText
            [attrStr removeAttribute:NSFontAttributeName range:range];
            [attrStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:newFont range:range];
            //found = YES;
        }
    }];
```

the code is clearly incomplete and it looks like its attempting to do it for fonts only.  I'd like to loop through every attribute and add it into a new `NSMutableAttributedString` variable.  Update: my question is how do I apply all attributes of one `NSMutableAttributedString` to another `NSMutableAttributedString` ?
Can we use this method `somehow:attribute:atIndex:effectiveRange`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is how do I apply all attributes of one NSMutableAttributedString to another NSMutableAttributedString ?

Comment: See my answer for the correct way to do this.

Answer (score -3):

`NSMutableAttributedString` (and `NSAttributedString`) conforms to `NSCopying`. So you should just be able to do this:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *mutableCopy = attrStr.mutableCopy;
NSAttributedString *immutableCopy = attrStr.copy;
```

Comment: i'd like to copy the attributes not the entire object.  Anyway i can get all the attribures in a dictionary perhaps and then copy them to all to a new attributedString ?